# Golang HTTP синхронизация

Tags: http, golang

Пишу Restful сервер с использованием патернов network_api -> data(UseCase->Repository).
Так как все http хендлеры обрабатываются параллельно, то каким образом корректно протянуть зависимости репозиториев и use_case объектов в слой network_api ?
То есть это будут синглтоны или же их нужно создавать для каждого отдельного request?
Потому как сейчас я боюсь за доступ к общим ресурсам. Например, use_case при загрузке читает json конфигурацию и в дальнейшем к ней обращается по многим путям из слоя nwtwork_api.

Есть какие нибудь best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, какие требования предъявляются к вашим данным (т.е именно модель данных ДИКТУЕТ требования к архитектуре).
Если ваши данные терпимы к параллельному одновременному доступу -- тогда не замарачивайтесь.
Если же нельзя одновременно из нескольких потоков обращаться к менеджеру данных -- тогда вводите глобальную блокировку. Фактически, такой глобальной блокировкой будет являться единственное соединение к базе данных.